# Lanelet2, earth->map transformation

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Autoware Community,

I would like to use a Lanelet2 map together with Autoware. I am able to visualize the Lanelet2 but the coordinate system is not clear. Lanelet2 is published in the map coordinate system, but what is the reference for this coordinate system? The coordinates do not correspond to UTM.

Where can I find the transformation between GNSS to Lanelet2 (earth -> map) ? I did not find anything in the Autoware.AI/Auto documentation where this can be configured. Is there somewhere a documentation about this transformation?

Thanks for your help!

Best,

Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360420/lanelet2,-earth-%3Emap-transformation/) by [mschratter](https://answers.ros.org/users/51444/mschratter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The coordinate system is with reference to the MGRS coordinate system instead of the UTM coordinate system. You will find this under the README file in the lanelet2_map_loader package.

---

Originally posted by [entropyboi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55041/entropyboi/) with karma: 16 on 2021-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0